# JavaMail - why it works on my laptop and not on another computer or server?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the following method to shoot emails:

```
protected void sendEmail(SmtpConnection smtpConnection, String recipients, String subject, String htmlBody, String filename, byte[] attachment) {

    final String user = smtpConnection.getUser();
    final String password = smtpConnection.getPassword();

    System.out.println(smtpConnection.getHost());
    System.out.println(smtpConnection.getPort());
    System.out.println(user);
    System.out.println(password);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpConnection.getHost());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpConnection.getPort());

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, 
            new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
        }
    });

    List<String> recipientList = Arrays.asList(recipients.split(","));

    InternetAddress[] iAddresses = new InternetAddress[recipientList.size()];

    for (String recipient : recipientList) {
        System.out.println("email sent to: " + recipient);
        try {
            iAddresses[recipientList.indexOf(recipient)] = new InternetAddress(recipient);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    subject = subject + " - " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object. 
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(smtpConnection.getUser()));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, iAddresses);

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);


        // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Now set the actual message
        messageBodyPart.setText(htmlBody);

        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        if (filename != null) {
            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            System.out.println(filename);

            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        }

        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent message successfully...");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The `SmtpConnection` contains all necessary configurations for sending email. On my laptop, it works just fine, but when I pass this jar to another person it simply cries and dies out after `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25, timeout -1;`

But host, port, user and password are correctly supplied from the `smtpConnection` object.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just for reference, is there a mail server operating on the laptop that would make using localhost succeed?

Comment: It's running CentOS 7. I installed it and, though I might be mistaken, I don't seem to remember installing a mail server. Shouldn't JavaMail work this out?

Comment: It's possible (though I'm not sure) that there might be some sort of MTA installed that is causing this behavior. Is there a process listening on port 25?

Comment: Funny thing is that the `smtpConnection` object defines port 587.

Comment: And, yeah! I found there's a MTA. Sendmail. But, shouldn't this implementation connect directly to the smtp server?

Comment: Who's creating the SmtpConnection object and what are the host and port values?  Someone has to configure it properly to refer to the mail server you want to connect to; JavaMail doesn't do that.  You almost certainly don't want it to connect to a mail server on your local machine.  Maybe there was a mail server running on the server machine so "localhost" worked there, but from your laptop you should configure it with the real host name of the server machine.

Comment: The SmtpConnection object is populated with correct values, unmarshalled from a REST webservices. For this case, host is  `smtp.fully.qualified.domain.name` and port is `587`.